# Java SwingWorker NullPointerException on model.reload() call

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am trying to add child nodes to a JTree inside a SwingWorker thread. Then reload the model to update the UI. When I reload the JTree DefaultModel it throws a NullPointerException. Is there a way to fix this? or do I have to find a different approach?

Here is what is happening.

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<String, Void>()
{

   @Override public String doInBackground()
   {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        return "hello";
   }

   @Override public void done()
   {
        String response = "";
        try {
            response = this.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        String device = "hello";
        ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();
        devices.add(device);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Devices");
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)this.deviceTree.getModel();

    for (String device : devices)
    {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(device);
        root.add(child);
        model.insertNodeInto(child, root, 0);
    }

        // Null pointer exception!!!
        model.reload();
    }
};
worker.execute();
```

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: I don't understand how `devices.add(device)` is valid. Where does `device` get initialized?

Comment: oops sorry ill take that out and put the stack trace in

Answer (score 0):

1) move all variables for

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Devices");
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)this.deviceTree.getModel();
```

outside from `SwingWorker` class

don't update `root` and `model`, really nothing from these `Object`,

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(device);
root.add(child);
model.insertNodeInto(child, root, 0);
```

only declare `ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();` and return that as `Object` if `SwingWorkers` ends (or decare as private variable),  if `SwingWokres` ends then create all `Object`

```
for (String device : devices) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(device);
    root.add(child);
    model.insertNodeInto(child, root, 0);
}
```

another options is declare [SwingWorkers#publish()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29);, but why care about that in this case

EDIT: on the left (top) side on this screen is `button labeled with SwingWorker`, read all `103` threads

Comment: I dont think im following your logic. What do you mean "only declare ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String(); and return that as object"

Comment: @Chris Watts you have to separate `JComponents` and its value, inside `SwingWorker` don't create any `JComponents`, `JComponent's Model`, just value for that, anyway as I said read other posts about `SwingWorker`, there are lots of options how to do it, maybe some of those posts will tell you more than ...

Comment: @mKorbel: It's OK to handle Swing code from within a SwingWorker's done method as the original poster is doing, since this is guaranteed to be called on the EDT.

Comment: @Hovercraft: Do you know why it is throwing an exception then?

Comment: @Chris: No, but that is because I think it likely that the reason for the exception is in code that has not been shown.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels with my respect to your person, no problem with your knowledges and skils with Generics, yes that's possible to create JComponents inside inner class that returns `new SwingWorker<String, Void>()` and from outside only NPE for newbie, that's similair/same problem as I cried, that you (both posters) was called model.fireXxxXxx inside SwingWorkers class, that job only for AbstactXxxModel, really don't do it, don't move that out, that's only good way to produce awlfully problems with RepaintManagers

Comment: @mKorbel: Sorry, but can you rephrase that. Also note that it wasn't me who down-voted you, but I'll up-vote this post to nullify the down-vote.